# Django foreign key pk in url as a parameter

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to call a foreign key pk in url as argument like:

```
{% for msg in msgs %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'home' msg.user.pk %}">Go</a>
        ...
        </Li>
{% endfor %
```

But it fails. Instead of, if I use **{{ msg.user.pk }}** in the template it works and I can see the pk.

The model is:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(...)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
```

Urls:

```
url(r'^home/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.home, name='home'),
```

Views:

```
def home(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        messages.info(request, 'Hello ' + user.username)
    ...

def messages_list(request):
    msgs = Message.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'messages.html', context={'msgs': msgs'})
```

The error:

```
Reverse for 'home' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['home/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

Comment: edit your question. show your urls

Comment: Can you also post the view that renders this templates?

Comment: Actually, we need the view that renders the template containing this url `<a href="{% url 'home' msg.user.pk %}">Go</a>` this is not enough to help figure out where the bug is...

Comment: I guess you have used namespace to register this url, means this url is inside your app urls.py file not in root urls.py file if so you need to prepend namespace seprated by colon i.e `{% url 'namespace:home' msg.user.pk %}`

Comment: But why can I retrieve pk outside the url but not inside?

Comment: Django find well the url but misses the pk, because of this message: `1 pattern(s) tried: ['home/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$'`

Comment: Outside the url I can see the user pk using {{ msg.user.pk }} and it is equal to 10 (which fits in regex part)

Comment: @P.Rodoreda please add your view, not the one of `home`

Comment: As everyone else has stated, post the correct view that renders the template that you're creating the link on.

Comment: Okey, I've updated the template too

Comment: it's because some of your `msgs` don't have the attribute `user` so, `msg.user` is None for them in your loop. Django will always raise `Reverse for 'home' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found.`

Comment: You're welcome: To deal with it, you can do this before using the URL: `{% if msg.user %}<a href="{% url 'home' msg.user.pk %}">Go</a>{% endif %}`